# Xcode build successfully but iOS Simulator didn't run

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've developed a camera app with the swift language. Build processing succeeded in Xcode and iOS Simulator was done.

But app list in iOS Simulator didn't include my app.
And an error occurred.What's wrong?

Two screenshots of my project are added below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your XCode with your project opened?

Comment: Add a link to the image, host it somewhere. Also, reset the simulator

Comment: you can upload screenshot  in http://postimage.org/index.php?um=computer or you can upload it to facebook or else where any of the host and give link.

Comment: Are you  trying in iOS device ??

Comment: have u checked macho linker to which it is set?

Comment: Check this MACH_O_TYPE it should be set to none or static library

Answer (score 15):

You can try this, it worked for me. 
Go to Product on top xcode. Follow this flow.

-> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select "Run" in the sidebar -> Info on tab -> Change the drop down box labeled Executable , changed it with your app. -> Close -> Run again.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this worked on my end. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Like Joel said, try changing the scheme that you are running. Right next to the simulator selector, there is the scheme selector; select it, then the project instead of the framework.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot it looks like you have the wrong scheme selected. Make sure you select the scheme for your iOS app, not the framework. The little dropdown to the right of the stop button in the upper-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Using any 3rd party libraries? 
Simulator relies on x86/x64 builds, but 3rd party libraries occasional don't have a matching binary for the simulator.

Result: Sim runs in to an error during compile while the app runs on a device. You should get an error in this case.